# Replace language specific characters in python with English letters

Tags: python, string, encoding, character-encoding, decoding

Is there any way in Python 3 to replace general language specific characters for English letters?
For example, I've got function `get_city(IP)`, that returns city name connected with given IP. It connects to external database, so I can't change the way it encodes, I am just getting value from database.
I would like to do something like:

```
city = "České Budějovice"
city = clear_name(city)
print(city) #should return "Ceske Budejovice"
```

Here I used Czech language, but in general it should work on any non Asian langauge.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
# coding=utf-8
from unidecode import unidecode

city = "České Budějovice"
print(unidecode(city))
```

Prints `Ceske Budejovice` as desired (assuming your post has a typo).

Note: if you're using Python 2.x, you'll need to decode the string before passing it to `unidecode`, e.g. `unidecode(city.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Could you please specify that this solutions is for Python 2.x and add the solution for Python 3.x (simply remove `decode('utf-8')`)? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `unicodedata` module for such cases.
 To get the needed result you should normalize the given string by using [unicodedata.normalize()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) and 
[unicodedata.combining()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.combining) functions:

```
import unicodedata

city = "České Budějovice"
normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', city)
new_city = u"".join([c for c in normalized if not unicodedata.combining(c)])

print(new_city)   # Ceske Budejovice
```

`NFD` is one of the four ***Unicode Normalization Forms***

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: does not work properly with polish Ł character

Answer (score 2):

Asongtoring above is almost correct - but in Python 3 it is a bit simpler as Pavlo Fesenko mentions in the comment to the solution. Here the solution in Python 3

```
from unidecode import unidecode

city = "České Budějovice"
print(unidecode(city))
```